# Query condition on entity reference field count

Tags: 8, database

I need to query an article with more than 1 tag (a field entity reference) in drupal entity query.

I tried this :

```
$query = Drupal::entityQuery('node')
                ->condition('type', 'article')
                ->condition('field_tags', 1, '>');
dd($query->execute());
```

But I got more than expected the articles id's and I don't why.

What is the good query to do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use the delta. This is explained here: [QueryInterface](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Query%21QueryInterface.php/function/QueryInterface%3A%3Acondition/8.2.x):

```
$query = Drupal::entityQuery('node')
            ->condition('type', 'article')
            ->condition('field_tags.%delta', 1, '>');
dd($query->execute());
```